# DevExpress XtraGrid Control - Stop Redraw On Datasource Update

Tags: devexpress, xtragrid

#### Scenario

I am using the latest version of DevExpress XtraGrid.
I am currently binding the DataView of a DataTable to the datasource of the gridcontrol in C#.
Since this DataTable gets updated every second, I have to refresh the gridcontrol.

#### ALSO

The DevExpress XtraGrid comes with the ability to automatically drag and drop the column headers into a group/sort like manner. This refresh problem I am having is particularly noticeable when I incorporate the use of the "group by column header" feature - In that the data that is grouped is collapsed under a single row. If I expand this row to see the data, it immediately shuts again upon Update - which at the minute is every second, rendering the grouping feature useless.

#### Question

How can I go about doing this without redrawing the whole thing?
I literally just want to see the numbers dynamically changing AND be able to use the grouping feature continually without it collapsing by itself when the rows of data update.

#### Current Code

```
        DataView dvw = latestCurve.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        dvw.Sort = "Ccy Asc AND Date Asc";
        this.gridControl2.DataSource = dvw;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your default view for gridControl2 is named gridView2:

```
gridView2.BeginUpdate();
try
{
    your code goes here
}
finally
{
    gridView2.EndUpdate();
}
```